# How to format string "1000-2000' to 10:00-20:00 in RUBY

Tags: ruby

Need to format string to format of time or string, doesn't matter. just needed to correspond the view like: `"1000-2000"` to `"10:00-20:00"`

Basically it is in my hash, so maybe you also know how to change all such values in my hash, that look like

```
{
  "Monday" => "1000-2000",
  "Tuesday" => "1000-2000",
  "Wednesday" => "1000-2000",
  "Thursday" => "1000-2000",
  "Friday" => "1000-1900",
  "Saturday" => "off",
  "Sunday" => "off"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
hash = {
  "Monday" => "1000-2000",
  "Tuesday" => "1000-2000",
  "Wednesday" => "1000-2000",
  "Thursday" => "1000-2000",
  "Friday" => "1000-1900",
  "Saturday" => "off",
  "Sunday" => "off"
}
hash.transform_values { |v| v.gsub(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '\1:\2') }
#=> { 
#     "Monday"=>"10:00-20:00",
#     "Tuesday"=>"10:00-20:00",
#     "Wednesday"=>"10:00-20:00",
#     "Thursday"=>"10:00-20:00",
#     "Friday"=>"10:00-19:00",
#     "Saturday"=>"off",
#     "Sunday"=>"off"
# }
```

Comment: maybe, you also know how to covert string "1000-2000" to "10:00-20:00"